# What's a good numerical/optimization software package for solving the 2-D optimal stopping problem?

Tags: optimization, pde, reference-request

I am looking for a numerical software package to help me solve the 2-dimensional "free boundary" PDEs that arise in optimal stopping problems.  In one dimension a standard optimal stopping problem in Economics is when to exercise an expansion option.  In the end, solving this problem comes down to solving the following ODE

$$
\mu x u' + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x^2 u'' + x k_0= r u
$$
such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
u(0) & =& 0 \\
u(\overline{x}) & =&  \frac{\overline{x}k_1}{r-\mu} - p\\
u'(\overline{x}) & = &  \frac{k_1}{r-\mu}.
\end{eqnarray}
A solution to this problem is a function $u$ together with the location of the boundary $\overline{x}$ - this is the so called "free boundary". This problem has a closed form solution.  In two dimensions, the problem no longer has a closed form solution.  The problem I want to solve is 
$$
 x k_0 + \mu x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ rw\frac{\partial u}{\partial w} + \frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(\sigma_x^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}  + \sigma_w^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial w^2} + 2\sigma_x\sigma_w \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial w}\right)  = r u
$$
such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
u(0,w) & = & 0\\
u(\overline{x}(w),w) & = & v(\overline{x}(w),w) - p \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(\overline{x}(w),w) & = & \frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(\overline{x}(w),w) \\
u(x,0) &= & \ell x \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial w}u(x,\overline{w}) & = & -1 \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial w^2}u(x,\overline{w}) & = & 0 \\
\end{eqnarray}

where $v$ is some known function of $x$ and $w$.  The solution of this problem will then be a function $u$ together with functions $\overline{x}(w)$ and $\overline{w}(x)$ that give the locations of the boundaries.

Do you know of any software packages that can solve these free boundary problems?  If so, can someone point me towards a reference or tutorial that might help?

Comment: Hi Prof. Glaser, welcome to scicomp, and nice meeting you on the bus to the airport!  I don't think you want OpenFOAM for this, but I'm not actually sure what the appropriate solver is.  I'm going to reframe your question a little so that it gets more attention, feel free to revert or fix any edits I make.

Comment: Hi Aron, it was good to meet you too.  Thanks so much for your help with the question!